# Extreme points of a set related to semidefinite cone

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-optimization

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetric matrix. Consider the following set
$$
\mathcal{C} = \{ X: X \succeq 0, \quad 0 \le X_{ij} \le 1, \forall i,j\}
$$
What are the extreme points of this set? What is changed if we also add the constraints $\sum_{j} X_{ij} = m$ for some integer $m < n$ and $\forall i$?

Comment: This site is not for homework.

Comment: That is interesting, because it seems to be a homework I have assigned to myself. Good to know that it feels like a homework problem to you. My specific question is that is there anything besides binary matrices an extreme point?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I would not expect this question to have a simple answer or to be homework.  The set $\mathcal{C}$ is not (for general $n$) polyhedral, so there must be more extreme points than just the binary matrices.  Also, the cone of doubly nonnegative matrices (positive semidefinite and elementwise nonnegative) is strictly larger than the cone of completely positive matrices (the convex hull of $xx^T$ for $x\geq 0$), so the extreme points are not just $xx^T$ for appropriately scaled $x$...

Comment: ... This problem asks about the intersection of the doubly nonnegative cone with some halfspaces; as far as I know the extreme rays of the doubly nonnegative cone have not been nicely characterized.

Comment: @Noah Stein: Thanks for pointing to "doubly nonnegative cone", I didn't know that it has a name! I also doubt that the question has a simple answer. The only case that it seems obvious to me is the $n=2$ case, where I can visualize how it looks.

Comment: @passerby51: You're welcome.  I voted to reopen this question, but I'm not sure whether others will join.  In any case, I'd bet that you can derive some partial results to your question from the partial results available by googling for "doubly nonnegative extreme ray" and probably not much else can be said at present.

Comment: I haven't heard "doubly nonnegative cone" before but in the convex optimization world, $\succeq$ applied to symmetric matrices implies a linear matrix inequality; i.e., $X$ above lies in the *semidefinite* cone. I'm inclined to leave this closed myself, though (not that I have the points in this SE to have a say). It's not off-topic, but I don't think it's concrete or specific enough.

Comment: @Noah Stein: Thanks again, pointing to that keyword was very helpful indeed.

Comment: Ah, I see now: the doubly nonnegative cone is the set of semidefinite matrices whose elements are all nonnegative.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant: Yes, that is true. I haven't heard of it before, and apparently there is a sizable literature talking about optimization over such cone (and a related object, the cone of co-positive matrices.)

Comment: Also there is the cone of completely positive matrices (which I defined above).  The doubly nonnegative matrices are a tractable outer approximation to this cone while the copositive matrices ($A$ such that $x^TAx\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$) are the dual of the completely positive matrices.  There is also a tractable inner approximation to the copositive matrices, though I don't think it has a name: it is given by sums of positive semidefinite and elementwise nonnegative matrices.